# Programmatically unsubscribe a YouTube user C#

Tags: c#, .net, api, youtube

Here is my code for a mass unsubscriber i am making, currently everything works - other than the unsubscribe feature.. (Typical huh)

```
   public void UnSubUsers()
   {
        string feedUrl = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/" + username.Text + "/subscriptions";
        YouTubeQuery query = new YouTubeQuery(feedUrl);
        subFeed = service.GetSubscriptions(query);
        YouTubeRequestSettings yts = new YouTubeRequestSettings("Unsubscriber", DEVKEY, username.Text, password.Text);
        YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(yts);
        int i = 0;
        int x = 0;
        x = (listBox1.Items.Count);
        for (i=0;i<x ;i++ )
        {
            string uname = listBox1.Items[i].ToString();
            uname=uname.Substring(42);
            uname = uname.Remove(uname.LastIndexOf("/"));
            Subscription s = new Subscription();
            s.Type = SubscriptionEntry.SubscriptionType.channel;
            s.UserName = uname;
            //MessageBox.Show(uname); //Displays the username so that we know if it is correct
            try
            {
                s.AtomEntry.EditUri = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/" + username.Text + "/subscriptions";
                s.SubscriptionEntry.EditUri = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/" + username.Text + "/subscriptions";
                request.Delete(s);
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString(), "Error");
            }
            catch (GDataRequestException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString(), "Error");
            }
        }
    }
```

(Also available at http://pastebin.com/LnKMYCJp)

When the code "reaches" request.Delete(s) it gives me this error:

```
Google.GData.Client.GDataRequestException: Execution of request failed: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/iWinterHD/subscriptions --->System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
    at Google.GData.Client.GDataRequest.Execute()
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at Google.GData.Client.GDataRequest.Execute()
    at Google.GData.Client.GDataGAuthRequest.Execute(Int32 retryCounter)
    at Google.GData.Client.GDataGAuthRequest.Execute()
    at Google.GData.Client.Service.Delete(Uri uriTarget, String eTag)
    at Google.GData.Client.FeedRequest1.Delete[Y](Y entry)
    at Unsubscriber.SubForm.UnSubUsers() in C:\Users\iWinterHD\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Unsubscriber\Unsubscriber\SubForm.cs:line 112
```

Does anybody know how to fix this, I have been trying to get this working for around 2 hours and I am still getting this error, no matter what I try

When i used fiddler to find out info about the connection this was the header:

```
DELETE /feeds/api/users/iWinterHD/subscriptions HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8
User-Agent: G-Unsubscriber/GDataGAuthRequestFactory-CS-Version=2.1.0.0--IEnumerable
X-GData-Key: key=DEVELOPER_KEY
Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=DQAAAMgAAAAfAWmos6z7rpaY8JrK2RNK4Urf7Riu_putKeGgV1KFH5OEmAYA2t5w0DWXbVQJnizQiPmLSl-4D0eCozYn5jVp4DWs4Rpao3udc3eTIC9wibBGRe640m7zZjl96UnFMyf-fJDk0VrTIcAw74S7_WhwBaRDjLS77EOWfERw066NmcYO-2QB_6WZ4Y0o3Y4haVn_pRokm8ckyuTRWJf6cES1yVlZ4fP5diUySVsH7EaHLiUcAquUl7GWCMdF_JbjRVVxvgeMW1zV757JW8l841uk
GData-Version: 2.0
Host: gdata.youtube.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

However the Google Developers example is this:

```
DELETE /feeds/api/users/default/subscriptions/SUBSCRIPTION_ID HTTP/1.1
Host: gdata.youtube.com
Content-Type: application/atom+xml
Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN
GData-Version: 2
X-GData-Key: key=DEVELOPER_KEY
```

Hopefully that gives a little heads up :)

Comment: Thankyou @Alain for editing the code into my post :) It just didn't seem to work for me..

Comment: Are you authenticated as the right user for performing delete actions on that users account?

Comment: @JamieDixon I was logged in as myself to test it, if that's what you mean?

Comment: My guess is that the api url you're using returns a collection of subscriptuions and what you're trying to do is perform a delete on that collection. I suspect you need to obtain the collection of subscriptions and loop through it, or pick a single subscription to delete. (This is purely a guess from looking at your code).

Comment: @JamieDixon, Correct - I am trying to get the collection to populate a listbox, then get the code above to strip the username from the listbox and delete the subscription

Comment: At the moment it looks like your code is firing a delete (using the delete VERB) to the URL of the feed which contains the username. That doesn't seem to be allowed since you're not specifying which subscripion to delete.

Comment: @JamieDixon, I thought that s.UserName defined which subscription i wanted to delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching through all the variables for around 4 hours i ended up stumbling upon the ID variable, which i later discovered needed to be passed to the final URL in order to remove the subscription WITH that ID, I tested it and it worked perfectly!

```
     public void ListSubs()
             {
                 string feedUrl = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/" + username.Text + "/subscriptions";
                 YouTubeQuery query = new YouTubeQuery(feedUrl);
                 try
                 {

                     subFeed = service.GetSubscriptions(query);

                     foreach (SubscriptionEntry entry in subFeed.Entries)
                     {
                         string id = entry.Id.AbsoluteUri;
                         id = id.Substring(id.LastIndexOf(":")+1);
                         listBox1.Items.Add(id);
                         string usrname = entry.Content.Src.Content;
                         usrname = usrname.Substring(42);
                         usrname = usrname.Remove(usrname.LastIndexOf("/"));
                         listBox2.Items.Add(usrname);
                     }
                 }
                 catch(GDataRequestException e)
                 {
                     MessageBox.Show(e.ToString(), "Error:");
                 }

             }

    public void UnSubUsers()
            {
                YouTubeRequestSettings yts = new YouTubeRequestSettings("Unsubscriber", DEVELOPER_KEY, username.Text, password.Text);
                YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(yts);
                int i = 0;
                int x = 0;
                x = (listBox1.Items.Count);
                for (i=0;i<x ;i++ )
                {
                    string uname = listBox1.Items[i].ToString();
                    yts = new YouTubeRequestSettings("Unsubscriber", DEVELOPER_KEY, username.Text, password.Text);
                    request = new YouTubeRequest(yts);
                    Subscription s = new Subscription();
                    s.Type = SubscriptionEntry.SubscriptionType.channel;
                    s.UserName = uname;
                    s.Id = listBox1.Items[i].ToString()
                    try
                    {
                        s.AtomEntry.EditUri = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/" + username.Text + "/subscriptions" + "/" + listBox1.Items[i].ToString();
                        request.Delete(s);
                    }
                    catch (ArgumentNullException e)
                    {

                    }
                    catch (GDataRequestException e)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
```

I had to add the subscription ID to the URL i was using to delete the subscription, here is my code to add the subscription ID to the listbox i originally used to store usernames, it turns out you can't pass usernames to the Delete method, but this works just as well because i added a second listbox to find the usernames of the subscription IDs

```
    string id = entry.Id.AbsoluteUri;
    id = id.Substring(id.LastIndexOf(":")+1);
    listBox1.Items.Add(id);
```

This code gets the subscription ID from the entry variable, you then add the subscription ID to the EditUri variable:

```
    s.AtomEntry.EditUri = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/" + username.Text + "/subscriptions" + "/" + listBox1.Items[i].ToString();
    request.Delete(s);
```

My mass unsubscriber is now complete!

Many thanks to @JamieDixon for all his wonderful help!

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of playing around with the API I think I've found the solution.

The `AtomEntry.EditUri` needs to be the same as the URI to the individual subscription. As it happens this is already stored in the `SubscriptionEntry` object (which you're overwriting).

Your code should look something like:

`itemToRemove.AtomEntry.EditUri = itemToRemove.SubscriptionEntry.EditUri;`

Here's the code I used to test this:

```
           var subscriptionsUrl = 
             "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/warmthonthesoul/subscriptions";
            var settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings([...]);
            var request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);

            var query = new YouTubeQuery(subscriptionsUrl);
            var feed = request.GetSubscriptionsFeed("warmthonthesoul").Entries;

            var itemToRemove = feed.SingleOrDefault(x =>
                                         x
                                         .SubscriptionEntry
                                         .Title.Text.Contains("Triforcefilms"));

            if(itemToRemove != null)
            {
                itemToRemove.AtomEntry.EditUri = itemToRemove
                                                    .SubscriptionEntry
                                                    .EditUri;
                request.Delete(itemToRemove);
                Console.WriteLine("Item removed");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: Thankyou for this method, I have tried this and my new method and I find my method more efficient, nevertheless thank you for all of your help, I wouldn't have been able to finish the mass unsubscriber without your help! :)

Comment: @Synthetic Glad to hear you've got it working! Just to point out, the code I've provided isn't a method I'm recommending, just the way I tested my theory. Ultimately all I'm pointing to is that you can set the `EditUri` of your `AtomEntry` to the same value as the `EditUri` of the `SubscriptionEntry`. I think this is more efficient than re-building the `EditUri` string from scratch. Which ever route you choose I'm glad you've got it up and running. :)